# How to define a Pattern Tokenizer in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to set up a [Pattern Tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) globally in config/elasticsearch.yml or with API call? I looked [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) but still no results.

**I tried the following:**
1. add to config/elasticsearch.yml

```
index :
  analysis :
    tokenizer :
      KeywordPatternAnalyzer :
        type : pattern
        pattern : \\W+
```

2. perform call

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d '{
  "analysis" : {
    "tokenizer":{
      "KeywordPatternAnalyzer":{
        "type":"pattern",
        "pattern":"\\W+"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**And tested like this:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=KeywordPatternAnalyzer' -d 'this is a test'
```

which returns

```
{"error":"ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find global tokenizer under [KeywordPatternAnalyzer]]","status":400}
```

Comment: did you try calling into an actual index like `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/_analyze?tokenizer=KeywordPatternAnalyzer' -d 'this is a test'`